# Sublime Text 3 file name abbreviation in tabs

Tags: sublime-text-3

I often work with text files with very long file names, and consequently the tabs are really really wide and thus inconvenient and ugly. How do I make it so that Sublime 3 doesn't display the whole file name, but only a part of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to:

Preferences -> Settings - User

And add `"enable_tab_scrolling": false` to your settings file.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and voilà, tabs are displayed as they used to be in sublime 2.

Comment: @JasonAller: Congratulations on reaching 2000 rep points.  (I have a sense of *déjà vu*.)

Answer (score 1):

"Enable_tab_scrolling" doesn't resolve the described problem. Honestly, I doesn't understand why another answer have so many upvotes. Nothing personal, but someone could think, that posted answer could actually resolve the problem, while it is not true.

Sorry if I sound rude, it just my lack of language skills.

*The answer:*

It is currently impossible, even with plugins, as I know. You can rename tab name (to trim it, say, to 20 characters), but this also would rename a filename itself, sadly.

If you want to try it yourself, launch console (Ctrl+`) and then type:

```
view.set_name("New tab name")
```

More info could be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197713/maximum-tab-width

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288789/how-can-i-change-tab-name-in-sublime-text

update:

https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/194

Comment: You're right in that the other answer doesn't really resolve my problem, but it's better than nothing so I accepted it. What I really want is to be able to set a maximum size of the tabs but still enable it to scroll, which according to you is impossible. Thank you for your answer though.